# Create feature class with desired fields using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, fields-attributes

When you create a feature class through ArcCatalog you get a handy menu that lets you assign fields.

[image]

I'm wondering if there isn't an arcpy equivalent. There's no arguments for it in the [Create Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-feature-class.htm) tool.

I thought maybe a field info object would do it, placed in the template variable, but this failed. I then realized that field info fields don't indicate field type or most any other field properties, so this should not have been a surprise.

```
>>> fi = arcpy.FieldInfo ()
>>> fi.addField ("TestField", "TestField", "VISIBLE", "NONE")
>>> arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (outLoc, outName, "POLYGON", fi)
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1806, in CreateFeatureclass
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
>>>
```

Currently I add each field one at a time after creating the feature class, but I'm thinking adding the fields at the time of feature class creation would be more efficient.

Comment: Use fieldinfo when creating layer from feature class.

Comment: The real cost of AddField is when rows exist. That said, I use SQL to CREATE TABLE the use that table as a template in Create Feature Class. Creating an empty table and adding fields is yet another option.

Comment: You have the option of a template feature class when using CreateFeatureClass or you could create an XML workspace document and import that instead of creating a feature class http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000014s000000. In reality the penalty of adding a field to a new empty feature class should be fairly small... The ArcObjects method would run faster but is *many* times more tedious than arcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the performance penalty of using AddField to add each field is small enough to make the functionality you seek be unnecessary.

At times in the past I know I have played with creating an empty table with the fields, when I know I want to add the same fields frequently, and used JoinField to add them in one step.

I also messed around with numpy.array and arcpy.da.ExtendTable at [Creating numpy.array with variable number of fields to test arcpy.da.ExtendTable performance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99792)